# Imagemagick processing performance issue

Tags: macos, imagemagick, homebrew, imagemagick-convert

Using Imagemagick 7 and have it installed on various Macs (imacs, macbook pro) sierra, high sierra, yosemite

I am trying to convert 300 plus multipage tiffs to single jpegs.

This is what I'm using

```
convert '*.*' /Users/ODI2/Desktop/JpegCopies/image-%d.jpeg
```

or

```
magick '*.*' /Users/ODI2/Desktop/JpegCopies/image-%d.jpeg
```

There seems to be a performance issue, sometimes I can convert up to 15 of the tiff documents, but only that many. Then sometimes the computers won't even do that. The file sizes are rough 1.5 to 3mb at max, 2500 x 4000px

So what can I do to be able to get this computers to process all these tiffs and jpegs? I can't seem to find a good answer on how to get the process to work right. This should be an extreme simply process for Imagemagick and the Macs.

Any help would be awesome!

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to load hundreds of images at once.

Hopefully you installed **ImageMagick** with **homebrew**, which means you can install **GNU Parallel** with:

```
brew install parallel
```

Then make a backup and test with just a few copies of your files. **GNU Parallel** will run multiple convert jobs in parallel, one per CPU core, so if you have 4 CPU cores, it will keep 4 convert jobs running at a time till all 300 files are done. You can change that with `parallel -j2` if you just want 2 at a time, for example.

So, you can hopefully do:

```
mkdir -p /Users/ODI2/Desktop/JpegCopies

parallel --bar --dry-run 'convert {} /Users/ODI2/Desktop/JpegCopies/{.}_%d.jpg' ::: *.tif
```

If that looks good, you can remove the `--dry-run` and do it again for real.

Comment: Thanks Mark, it looks like its working. But does this still break open the multi file tif and then make them jpeg all with staying in the same order? Example:   1.tiff has 5 pages in it 1 2 3 4 5,        it will become 1.jpeg 2.jpeg 3.jpeg 4.jpeg 5.jpeg etc

Comment: How did you get on?